# Error: class "ofTexture" has no member "getTextureReference"

Tags: opengl, textures, shader, openframeworks

I'm finishing up my second semester of C++ programming and have wanted to spice up my output. I'm fairly familiar with C++ but very new to oF. I've been following along with the tutorials in the oF book from the site and am on the Shaders chapter working with textures: http://openframeworks.cc/ofBook/chapters/shaders.html#addingtextures

In this section, I'm getting an error (I'm using Visual Studio): class "ofTexture" has no member "getReferenceTexture".

```
#include "ofApp.h"

void ofApp::setup() {
    // setup
    plane.mapTexCoordsFromTexture(img.getTextureReference());
}

void ofApp::draw() {

    // bind our texture. in our shader this will now be tex0 by default
    // so we can just go ahead and access it there.
    img.getTextureReference().bind();

    // start our shader, in our OpenGL3 shader this will automagically set
    // up a lot of matrices that we want for figuring out the texture matrix
    // and the modelView matrix
    shader.begin();

    // get mouse position relative to center of screen
    float mousePosition = ofMap(mouseX, 0, ofGetWidth(), plane.getWidth(), -plane.getWidth(), true);

    shader.setUniform1f("mouseX", mousePosition);

    ofPushMatrix();
    ofTranslate(ofGetWidth()/2, ofGetHeight()/2);
    plane.draw();
    ofPopMatrix();

    shader.end();
    img.getTextureReference().unbind();

}
```

I opened up the ofTexture.h and .cpp files and sure enough there's no member called getTextureReference. I've browsed through the oF site and forum, looked through Stack Exchange, and did a google search but I'm not getting a clear picture of what this call is supposed to do to see if there's a work around or another function I should be calling.
Has ofTexture::getTextureReference been replaced with something else? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret the openframeworks source correctly you can call [bind](http://openframeworks.cc/documentation/gl/ofTexture/#show_bind) directly on your `ofTexture`.

If its an instance of `ofVideoGrabber` you need to call [getTexture](https://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/gettexturereference-deprecated-in-v0-9-0/21449)